# How to fix an error with adding integers in Java?

Tags: java

In given example:

```
int a, b, c;
a = 2111000333;
b = 1000222333;
c = a + b;
System.out.println("c= " + c);
```

will return: `c= -1183744630` , why?

How to fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your integer is overflowing. An integer has a maximum value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2^31 - 1). If the value becomes bigger, your variable will not have the right value anymore.

A long has a bigger range.

```
long a, b, c;
a = 2111000333;
b = 1000222333;
c = a + b;
System.out.println("c= " + c);
```

Comment: @Scharrels - what if it's needs to stay as integer?

Comment: If it needs to stay an int, you could cast the long value to an integer, `int newInt = (int) c;`. Although, I am not completely sure if this would be a good approach.

Comment: You cannot put values this big in an integer, so you're stuck then. If you need to do part of your calculations with big values, which will become small afterwards, cast your integers to longs, do the calculations and cast them back. However, be aware that the value must be smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE when you cast it back.

Comment: @reg: Remember that in Java integral types are *always* signed and you *cannot* detect overflow except when using a larger type. That's by design and yes, in some cases actually unfortunate.

Comment: But how can I predict how big variable will became? Should we declare 'doubtful' variables (e.g. account balance) as long by default?

Comment: @mary.ja, that is a domain specific decision.  If you cannot tell how big your numbers may be, and accuracy is needed, you must use another type of number instead of the native types.  I believe BigDecimal is the typical suggestion for this.

Comment: A Java int is always 2^32-1 (defined by the language). Your statement of "typically 2^32 - 1" is incorrect.

Comment: an int in java is signed, so Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2^31 -1 not 2^32 -1

Comment: I'm not sure why it would need to stick to `int` s, but keep in mind that a `long` is only 8 bytes, so it's unlikely that you'll need to avoid using them because of memory concerns.

Answer (score 9):

The MAX_VALUE of a Java long is 9223372036854775807, so Scharrels' solution works for your example.

Here's another solution that can go even higher, should you need it.

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(2111000333);
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(1000222333);
BigIntegerc = a.add(b);
System.out.println("c= " + c);
```

This approach is bounded only by JVM memory.

Comment: I would check `if (b > LONG.MAX_VALUE - a)` before going for heavy `BigInteger` object.

Answer (score 4):

```
long a, b, c;
a = 2111000333;
b = 1000222333;
if (b > LONG.MAX_VALUE - a) {
   // a and b cannot be added.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of an int in Java is 2,147,483,647.
When you want to compute something over this value, you must use the **long** type.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Datatypes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647